# $\int_{a}^b f(x)dx=\int_{a}^b x f(x)dx=0$, how to prove there are more than two zeros in $[a,b]$

Tags: integration, analysis

$f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
One zero point follows easy from Intermediate Value Theorem and $\int_{a}^b f(x)dx=0$, but similar trick does not work for more zeros.

Comment: "More" than two zeros is incorrect - that should be "at least" two. For example, choose $a >1$ so that $\int_{-a}^a x^2 - 1\, dx = 0$ (you can compute $a$, it is $\sqrt 3$, but that is irrelevant). The integral of $x f(x)$ will automatically be zero because it's an odd function and the interval is symmetric around $0$. And the function has exactly two zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

In fact, you have that $$\int_a^b f(x)(nx-m)dx=0$$
for all $n,m\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Does this imply more than two zeros of $f$?

Comment: Out of interest, why limit to $n,m \in \mathbb {Z} $?

Comment: @coffeemath The function is continuous. If it has one zero $\alpha$, $f(x)$ is positive on one "side" of $\alpha$, negative on the other. What happens if you integrate $(x-\alpha)f(x)$? And there is at least one zero because the integral of $f(x)$ vanishes. Interestingly, you can generalize to $(x-\alpha_1)(\dots)(x-\alpha_n)f(x)$: you get a function that is positive (or negative, but not both) on every subinterval, if $f(x)$ has $n$ zeros.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for your hint, together with Surb's, I know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @Nick I was a bit sloppy in my comment: you multiply by $(x-\alpha)$ only if $f(x)$ changes sign at $\alpha$. If it's a zero without sign change, you don't multiply, but it's similar to the case when there are no zeros at all. The same applies to the general case where there are severals (distinct) zeros $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$: only multiply by the factors $(x-\alpha_i$)$ where there is a sign change at $\alpha_i$.

Comment: There need only be two zeros. See mathguy's comment.